# Getting `NoMethodError` error when trying to use ActiveJob::Exceptions retry_on method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

For some reason, I'm getting an error when I am trying to use ActiveJob::Exceptions `retry_on` method. The docs show this usage:

```
class RemoteServiceJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on CustomAppException # defaults to 3s wait, 5 attempts

  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

But when I do this, I'm getting an undefined method error:

> "undefined method `retry_on'...(NoMethodError)"

My code is exactly like the above, except that I am retrying on a different error. The class where I am attempting to do this is a job that inherits from a `BaseJob` classt that inherits from `ActiveJob::Base`.

Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting this result? Why wouldn't the method be defined if I'm extending `ActiveJob::Base`?

Comment: What is your rails version?

Comment: It is: `v4.2.11.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [retry_on](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/65f9e0c4bbc56f208cb6b2329d890c6d9935da1d/guides/source/5_1_release_notes.md#notable-changes-7) got added to Rails 5.1. It is not available before 5.1. As you said, you are using Rails 4, so the exception is legitimate.